# Can superpowers come to exist without wars of expansion?

Tags: society, warfare, economy

Our world is surrounded by a magic barrier that keeps out eldritch abominations that exist in the void, such as Cthulhu⁠. However, this barrier is fairly sensitive and easily damaged⁠. The violent, metaphysical energies of warfare between humans can disrupt the barrier, tearing sections of it open and allowing the void monsters an easy path through⁠. In order to prevent this the gods have decreed that warfare is illegal⁠. Any nation or person violating this law will be punished courtesy of a lightning bolt⁠.

With armed conflicts being banned, nations must find alternatives to solving issues with each other. Therefore, a focus has been made on economic warfare to prevent excessive violence. Sabatoge, selling and stealing of trade secrets, blackmail, technological races, followed by the occasional assassination of specific targets. While peace seems to prevail on the surface, it hides a ruthless underbelly of conflict that hides in the shadows.

Every empire or superpower has had a history of violent expansion in our world, either for ideological reasons or simply resources. Would it be possible for these powers such as the British empire, USSR, or the US to come to be when violent warfare is taken off the table ? How big can pires get under these conditions?

Comment: This is another one of these questions. As big as you like. You've already given yourself the way to do it. If the entire world doesn't do conventional wars, the size is arbitrary. I also don't see how this is true world building/isn't this backwards again? Why don't you have a superpower in mind and then ask how they got there?

Comment: Yes. This is one of those easily answered questions because it is entirely plot based. The author is free to create any chain of events within nir world as desired.

Comment: We need a clear definition of "war" to have any hope of answering this question. Are multiple targeted assassinations a war? Is military operation against a drug cartel or religious extremists a war?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your gods' definition of war, it is entirely possible to have superpowers without wars. Maybe through intrigue and certain arranged "circumstances" happening to key people in other nations would force those nations to turn to others, where in turn, they can slowly exploit them for personal gain.

If you don't already know about it, you can check out *No Game; No life* by author Yu Kamiya, a Japanese light novel/manga/anime that has the exact same constraint in the world the story takes place in.
In short, gamer siblings get transported to a world where *everything* is decided by games. The games can be whatever the people playing agree upon. One of the overarching plot points of the series is how the two of them use skill and strategy to expand their nation's power and borders.